# Hey is that ETH.Capitalseo.com is part of Stalking process of ETH organizations

Tags: mining, staking, scam

I been investing Capitalseo.com where they say it's part of ETH organization. Please tell me they are real or scams. I invested so far 118k NZ dollar and they asking me more deposit into my wallet for successfully withdraw

Comment: Hi, this sounds like an absolute scam, never heard of it and the top google result is from scamwatcher with people saying similar. But you could add context such as how you access this "account", and the addresses of the smart contacts you deposited to or wallets you sent money to. You most likley can only contact the police. Please be careful and good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `Capitalseo.com` is related to the Ethereum foundation at all.

If you search the name of the website on google, you can see [some](https://scamwatcher.org/eth-capitalseo-com-review/) [links](https://www.scamdoc.com/view/1379993) of people that have [reviewed the site negatively](https://www.scamwatcher.com/scam/view/679230#comment-1142503), literally calling it a "*scam site*".

Anyone who tells you to deposit money in order to withdraw, (ignoring gas costs), is trying to scam you.

If you are trying to invest in Ethereum, you are better off using a well-known CEX or a DEX, and directly buying ETH.

Some examples of popular CEXs are [Coinbase](https://www.coinbase.com/), [Binance](https://www.binance.com/en), [Kraken](https://www.kraken.com/), and [Gemini](https://www.gemini.com/).

Some examples of popular Dexs are [Uniswap](https://uniswap.org/), [Aave](https://aave.com/), [Compound](https://compound.finance/), [MakerDAO](https://makerdao.com/en/).

You may have lost some money, but you've learned a valuable lesson that should keep you from repeating the same mistake in the future. Always practice due diligence when sending real funds to a smart contract or DeFi protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Important Warning: Beware of eth.capitalseo.com - A Scam Website

I want to share my experience and urge everyone to stay away from eth.capitalseo.com. This website is a complete scam, and I fell victim to their deceptive tactics.

I invested in eth.capitalseo.com, promising lucrative returns through daily rewards. They assured me that after a month, I could withdraw my earnings. However, they conveniently left out crucial details.

First, they insisted I pay a security fee, which I reluctantly did. But when I tried to withdraw my money, they demanded a tax payment. I paid that too, only to face another demand – a platform fee.

None of these additional conditions were mentioned in their terms and conditions. It became apparent that they were using these tactics to trap and exploit unsuspecting individuals like me.

This behavior is not just fraudulent; it's outright bullying. I implore you, please refrain from engaging with eth.capitalseo.com. Protect your hard-earned money and avoid falling into their traps. Spread the word to protect others from this deceitful website.

Feel free to use this note to warn others about the website's fraudulent activities. It's crucial to help prevent others from becoming victims of similar scams.